# Using enum in the form of files named *.enum.ts in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ienumerable, tsconfig

I am developing an Angular application and I want to use enum and write the names of the enum files as follows:

```
*.enum.ts
```

Unfortunately, after using enum in this way, I encounter the following error

```
Cannot find name '*'
```

To solve this problem, is it the right way to change `tsconfig.app.json` as below?

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.enum.ts" // should add this line?
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you importing the enums? Are your files *literally* named `*.enum.ts` or is it just a naming scheme?

Comment: I personally want to name it this way @caTS

Comment: Is the file named `*.enum.ts` or are the files named like `EnumOne.enum.ts` and `EnumTwo.enum.ts`. I'm asking if your file name is *literally* `*.d.ts`.